# R: aggregate by all factor levels (present and not present)

Tags: r, aggregate, dplyr

I can aggregate a `data.frame` trivially with `dplyr` with the following:

```
z <- data.frame(a = rnorm(20), b = rep(letters[1:4], each = 5))

library(dplyr)

z %>%
  group_by(b) %>%
  summarise(out = n())

Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

       b   out
  (fctr) (int)
1      a     5
2      b     5
3      c     5
4      d     5
```

However, sometimes a dataset may be missing a factor.  In which case I would like the output to be `0`.

For example, let's say the typical dataset should have 5 groups.

```
z$b <- factor(z$b, levels = letters[1:5])
```

But clearly there aren't any in **this particular** but could be in another.  How can I aggregate this data so the `length` for missing `factors` is `0`.

Desired output:

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

       b   out
  (fctr) (int)
1      a     5
2      b     5
3      c     5
4      d     5
5      e     0
```

Comment: You can use `tapply` like this `tapply(z$b, z$b, length)`

Comment: I think this is an [open issue on github](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/341).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to approach this is to use `complete` from "tidyr". You have to use `mutate` first to factor column "b":

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

z %>%
  mutate(b = factor(b, letters[1:5])) %>%
  group_by(b) %>%
  summarise(out = n()) %>%
  complete(b, fill = list(out = 0))
# Source: local data frame [5 x 2]
# 
#        b   out
#   (fctr) (dbl)
# 1      a     5
# 2      b     5
# 3      c     5
# 4      d     5
# 5      e     0
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to join with a table containing all levels:

```
z <- full_join(z, data.frame(b=levels(z$b))
```

This will set all the missing rows for your analysis variables to NA, which in the general case would make more sense than setting them to zero. You can change them to zero if necessary with `z[is.na(z)] <- 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use xtabs:

```
xtabs(a ~ b, z)
```

This aggregates z$b rather than just counting levels in z$a as in your example, but that's easily achieved with table:

```
table(z$a)
```